# Pandoc Column Width for Twocolumn not working

Tags: latex, pandoc, pdflatex, xelatex

I cannot get column width recognized. It is as if it is just ignored and each column is exactly 50% of the available space. Additionally the example implies I can tell it when I want the 2nd column to start but that is also ignored.

The following is from the Pandoc manual column example, but when I compile it via pandoc they are just each 50% width not what is specified. The frontmatter in my example was not provided in their example but its what I figure it must be to get the columns working. I've tried this with and without the frontmatter.

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 within WSL2 and pandoc version:

> pandoc 2.17.1.1 Compiled with pandoc-types 1.22.1, texmath 0.12.4,
> skylighting 0.12.2, citeproc 0.6.0.1, ipynb 0.2

I'm using these command line entry for compiling it: (I've also tried pdflatex engine as well)

```
pandoc mat_doc.md --pdf-engine=xelatex -o mat_doc.pdf
```

Here is the file:

```
---
output: pdf_document 
classoption: twocolumn
---

:::::::::::::: {.columns}
::: {.column width="60%"}

contents

:::
::: {.column width="40%"}

contents

:::
::::::::::::::
```

How do I get different sized columns? Why does this not work per their manual?  Thx!

Comment: Can you add a link yo the `Pandoc manual column example` you are revering to? I think you are mixing two different approaches for columns.

Comment: This one: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#columns

Comment: Note that the example is in the section on slide shows. Columns work with beamer, revealjs etc, but not with plain latex.

Comment: Is there another way to create columns? specifically ones i can size or turn off and on without making the entire document a twocolumn one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beamer columns you are trying to use, are something special in the beamer class and don't work with normal classes.

However under the hood, these columns are just glorified minipages - and these you can use in normal latex classes.

```
---
output: pdf_document 
---

\noindent\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
test
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
test
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Thank you this works for my purposes!